# Two custom taxonomies in permalink structure

Tags: permalinks

I'm struggling setting up custom permalink structure with custom taxonomies. I've read many questions/answers here but I can't get it to work (most frustrating is that I don't know of a way to debug and find the problem myself). Any help is greatly appreciated!

**What you need to know**

- I have a custom post type called `items`
- `items` has  two custom taxonomies:

  - `types` and `locations`.
- Every item is associated with **one** `type` and **multiple (1+)** `locations`

I'm trying to get this link structure for every `item`:

`http://domain.com/type/location`

whereas I only want the first location term to be used in this link structure.

I haven't tried implementing the `/location` part of the link structure (I guess that's a little bit more complex), as I'm already struggling with the `/type/` part. So my code currently looks like this and this doesn't yield any changes in my permalinks:

**in a plugin**

```
register_post_type( 'item',
        array(
            'labels'        => $labels,
            'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments'),
            'public'        => true,
            'has_archive'   => true,
            'rewrite'       => true,
            'menu_icon'    => plugins_url( '/img/icon.png'),
            'menu_position' => 42,
            'categories'    => array( ),
        )
    );


register_taxonomy( 'types', 'item', array(
        'labels'       => $item_types_labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'query_var'    => 'type',
        'rewrite'      => true,
        'public'       => true,
        'show_ui'      => true,
    ) );
```

**in functions.php**

```
add_filter('post_link', 'types_permalink', 10, 3);
add_filter('post_type_link', 'types_permalink', 10, 3);

function types_permalink($permalink, $post_id, $leavename) {
    if (strpos($permalink, '%types%') === FALSE) return $permalink;

        // Get post
        $post = get_post($post_id);
        if (!$post) return $permalink;

        // Get taxonomy terms
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'types');   
        if (!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms) && is_object($terms[0])) $taxonomy_slug = $terms[0]->slug;
        else $taxonomy_slug = 'no-type';

    return str_replace('%types%', $taxonomy_slug, $permalink);
}
```

I set my permalink structure to the custom structure `/%types%/%postname%/`. 
My URL still looks like this `domain.com/item/postname`.

Also: Whatever I put in place for `/item/` (e.g. `domain.com/this-doesn-make-sense-to-me/postname`), I get redirect to `domain.com/item/postname`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First issue- the permalink structure in Settings is only for the `post` post type, so your `post_type_link` function has no `%types%` tag to replace.

Second- unless you want a very complicated (and less performant) solution, the simpler solution is to have a static prefix in your post type slug. With the URL `http://domain.com/type/location/post-name/`, WordPress has no way of knowing what you're asking for. Is `type` a page with child page `location`, or is it a `types` taxonomy term? Using the standard rewrites system, one rule will always take precedence, and the other requests will always 404. With the URL format `http://domain.com/item/type/location/post-name/`, WordPress will know exactly what you're asking for, because only one post type is prefixed with `item`.

As for specifics- in your post type registration, set the `slug` argument of `rewrite` to the format of URL you want:

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'item/%types%' ),
```

… and your `post_type_link` filter should work. If you want to add locations, just add that tag to the slug and add the code to replace the tag in your `post_type_link` filter-

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'item/%types%/%locations%' ),
```